# Run two keydown codes for arrow keys

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two areas on the same page I wish to have arrow keys doing something (two different things).

The problem is, if I have the following code, only once is executed.

```
   $(document).keydown(function (evt) {
        if (evt.keyCode == 37) {          
            evt.preventDefault();
            // CODE
        } else if (evt.keyCode == 39) { 
            evt.preventDefault();
            // CODE
        }
    });

   $(document).keydown(function (evt) {
        if (evt.keyCode == 37) {          
            evt.preventDefault();
            // CODE
        } else if (evt.keyCode == 39) { 
            evt.preventDefault();
            // CODE
        }
    });
```

How can I have it so two are executed? I can't see how I could use classes, as its the arrow keys, not a click function.

Comment: I have updated my question. I want the left and right arrow buttons to work for two different things on the same page. Once when a div is 'display: none' the other when its 'display:block'. I tried triggering it with this but it didn't work.

Comment: It appears to work fine - http://jsfiddle.net/8rgnzmk5/

Comment: @Joe I dont understand what you mean. I want one set to do one thing, another to do the other. How can I make the code know that when I press the arrow keys at one point to this, on another do that.

Comment: You have 2 textareas and you want your arrow keys work differently in those two areas?

Comment: I have a popup which shows. When this popup is open use one set of code, when its closed use the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has a `:visible` meta selector: http://jsfiddle.net/8rgnzmk5/1/

```
$(document).keydown(function (evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 37 || evt.keyCode == 39) {          
        evt.preventDefault();

        if (evt.keyCode == 37) {
            if ($target.is(':visible')) {
                // left, visible
            } else {
                // left, invisible
            }
        } else if (evt.keyCode == 39) {
            if ($target.is(':visible')) {
                // right, visible
            } else {
                // right, invisible
            }
        }
    }
});
```